# Función asignar nombre a variables - Python

Tags: python, funciones, dataframe

Un problema común con el que me encuentro es el de poder especificar el nombre de una variable en una función sin conocer dicho nombre a priori, por ejemplo:

Supogamos que tengo una función cuya salida es un dataframe, me gustaría poder especificar el nombre de ese dataframe en relación a otro parámetro:

Ejemplo:

```
data_prueba = pd.DataFrame([1,5,3,2])

    def cambiar_y_guardar_nombre(data):
        n = len(data)        # n=4 
        data.to_csv("data_4.csv")   # ¿Cómo puedo especificar que se guarde como "data_4"?

cambiar_y_guardar_nombre(data_prueba)
```

Espero haberme explicado, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con formatear la cadena con la ruta del archivo de destino, por ejemplo:

```
data_prueba = pd.DataFrame([1,5,3,2])

def cambiar_y_guardar_nombre(data):
    n = len(data)
    data.to_csv(f"data_{n}.csv")

cambiar_y_guardar_nombre(data_prueba)
```

Si quieres poder modificar el nombre de base, puedes hacer algo como:

```
def cambiar_y_guardar_nombre(data, base_name="data"):
    n = len(data)
    data.to_csv(f"{base_name}_{n}.csv")

cambiar_y_guardar_nombre(data_prueba)
cambiar_y_guardar_nombre(data_prueba, base_name="foo")
```

Comment: Me vas a solucionar todas las dudas tu solo hombre. Gracias un saludo!